# Convert mailing list users to the Stack Exchange engine?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, new-users, publicity

I'm new to public mailing lists, other than those at my workplace. I was browsing the [`pgf-users` mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=pgf-users) and I find that many of the questions come from end-users. Such questions perfectly fit the StackExchange format.

I was wondering if anybody ever sent out invitations to join TeX StackExchange. I don't know what the social implications will be to the traditional mailing list community. I mean, why would I opt for the mailing list when there is StackExchange which is suitable for end-user questions?

Well, to start off, I think the mailing list is still a good tool for focused developer groups.

Answer (score 9):

As a mailing list subscriber, I don't think I would appreciate posts specifically advertising TeX.SX. However, sometimes I will post a link to an answer on the site in response to a question on a mailing list.  This is entirely appropriate, and is a good way to publicize the site without explicit advertising.

Answer (score 7):

[At TUG 2011 Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/going-to-a-conference-the-tug-2011-experience) made [a presentation of TeX.SX](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/bringing-together-tex-users-online/) which is relevant in converting mailing list users. It includes a comparison of different communication forms and lists some advantages of TeX.SX.