# Going to a conference - the TUG 2011 experience

Tags: discussion, tug, speakers-bureau, conferences

This is an overview of my attendance at the [TeX Users Group Conference 2011](http://tug.org/tug2011/). My extensive reports can be read [on our blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/tag/conferences-2/), and as there are many related meta site posts, I will

- Compile a list of related internal links
- Show preparation, participation and post-treatment in chronological sequence

### Preparation

- Jeff posted [the offer to speaking sponsorships](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/possible-conference-speaking-sponsorships-2011), TUG 2011 has been chosen
- I asked, [who of us would go there](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/who-plans-to-go-to-the-tug-2011-conference-in-india)
- Prepared abstract, sent to TUG, which had been [accepted](http://tug.org/tug2011/program.html)
- SE agreed in sponsoring
- [Became member](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/who-would-like-to-become-a-member-of-the-tex-user-group-sponsored-by-stack-exch) of TUG, [together with SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1528/do-we-want-stack-exchange-to-become-an-institutional-member-of-the-tug)
- Self-organizing flights, hotel, visa for India, conference registration
- Involving TeX.SX users also in the presentation of our site:

  - Selecting a great [question for attracting experts](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/which-question-would-you-choose-as-a-showcase-for-attracting-tex-experts)
  - Choosing a [great tag wiki for demonstration](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/who-designs-the-best-tag-wiki)
  - Discussing [pros and cons of TeX.SX compared to other systems](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-tex-sx-compared-to-usenet-groups-mailing-lists-an)
  - [Making use of the data explorer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/how-can-we-explore-the-content-of-tex-sx) for getting data to speak about

### At the conference

- Held a [presentation about TeX online communities](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/bringing-together-tex-users-online/) with a particular focus on TeX.SX, with a live demonstration of the site including chat and meta site, used contributions on above mentioned meta answers
- The talk has been live broad-casted on the Internet via [river-valley.zeeba.tv/broadcasting](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/broadcasting/), seen also [by chat users](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/conversation/tug2011)
- Made clear statement during the presentation that Stack Exchange fully sponsored my attendance
- Gave Stack Exchange swag to attendees (see [photo of swag table](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/tex-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users/1898#1898))
- Handed TeX.SX [business cards](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/tex-stack-exchange-moderator-cards) over to fellow participants, got some back
- Had a TeX.SX t-shirt on, also while speaking (see [the photo](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/tex-sx-t-shirts/1904#1904))
- Talked with fellow participants about the site among TeX topics

### After the conference

- Posted reports on the conference to our blog, already started during the conference:

  - [Day 1](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/tug-2011-day-one/)
  - [Day 2](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/tug-2011-day-two/)
  - [Day 3](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/tug-2011-day-three/)
- Published the presentation on [our blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/bringing-together-tex-users-online/), [my blog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/online/tex-online/), and on [slideshare.net](http://www.slideshare.net/StefanKottwitz/tex-online-communities)
- Informed about reports on our TeX blog on the conference mailing list, [LaTeX-Community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=413:tug-2011-reports&catid=44:news-latex&Itemid=111), [goLaTeX.de](http://www.golatex.de/news.php), also going to TeX feed aggregators such as [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/community/) and [planet.dante.de](http://planet.dante.de/)
- Preparing an article for the upcoming [TUGboat journal](http://tug.org/TUGboat/), the conference proceedings
- Suggested also using the daily reports in that journal
- The article will be translated for the German TeX user group journal (DANTE), either appearing soon or together with a presentation at the next DANTE conference
- I prepared an about 8 pages report about the conference in German to be appearing in the upcoming DANTE journal
- A video of the presentation has been published on the Internet, by river-valley.zeeba.tv, PDF slide show together with video and audio synchronized:

  - http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/bringing-together-tex-users-online-from-usenet-to-web-2-0-and-beyond/
  - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCt6ZM9Cn6A

Perhaps it's useful for somebody regarding next year's events or even as an example for other Stack Exchange sites. Answers and comments, such as what could be done better or differently, are very welcome!

Comment: as a participant at tug 2011, i'd like to compliment stefan on an interesting presentation and his general readiness to answer questions and be a good ambassador for tex.sx.  well done!

Comment: +1: Nice overview and summary! Fun to read even a decade later :).

Answer (score 14):

Thank you for bringing your experiences back to the community. Wow, and a blow-by-blow account for each day you were there. This is *exactly* the type of activity that makes these conference sponsorships worthwhile. It looks like everyone enjoyed your account of the conference. I hope we can do many more of them.

### Thank you and GREAT JOB!