# Who plans to go to DANTE 2012?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, sponsorship, conferences, speakers-bureau

The 46th general meeting of DANTE eV ([DANTE 2012](http://www.dante.de/events/dante2012_en.html)) will be held from March 7 to March 9 in Leipzig, Germany. As far as I know that's the biggest national TeX users group in the world.

Who would like to go there? Does anybody plan to speak?

Comment: Sounds fantastic! Will it be broadcasted? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Most likely not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll go there and plan to give a talk about high quality commercial/open source database publishing with TeX. I should send a proposal for the talk to the organizers.

Answer (score 6):

I will go to DANTE 2012 and make a talk about TeX online communities, similar to the talk at the [TUG 2011 conference](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/going-to-a-conference-the-tug-2011-experience) in India.

Luckily I don't need hotel or flight. I'll stay with relatives who live 50km from that city, so I'll just rent a car for those days.

The [program](http://www.dante.de/events/dante2012/Programm.html) already shows talks of Patrick, Herbert, Martin, Uwe and me, so some members of our site will be there and talk.

Comment: Your talk about Stackexchange from TUG2011 would be very welcome. And DANTE would most likely help with travel costs.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thanks, I'll make the talk! And SE offered me that they would cover car rental and conference fee. So of course I'll write on meta about the meeting and post a report on the TeX.SE blog.

Comment: @SteanKottwitz: See you Tuesday evening. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I'll be there and give my tutorial about TeX in the 21st century.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go, have a talk on labeling letters and the creation of photo albums.