# Why can I edit only some questions on Meta?

Tags: support, editing, meta, privileges

I can edit some questions (e.g. [Who are the package maintainers here?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1181/5763)), but only retag others (e.g. [Who plans to go to DANTE 2012?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2258/5763)). Why? I can edit all questions and answers on main.

Comment: In support of @doncherry's answer, [your latest edit on TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2051) was considered a "suggested edit". Suggested edits are peer-reviewed for [sub-2k-rep](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) users. Some edits are quickly reviewed, while more questionable ones are usually left for more experienced reviewers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maintainers question is a CW question, you only need 100 rep to edit these. The DANTE question is a regular question, you need 2000 rep to edit these, but only 500 rep to edit their tags, so you're in between with ~1.8k. Usually, however, you should be able to suggest edits while you're below 2000 rep, on the main site as well as on meta afaik. For more details on the privileges, check out the respective stages at https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/.

Comment: With the DANTE question I only get the retag button. When I manually change the link from the retag button (replacing `edit?tagsonly=true` with `edit`), I get the usual suggested edit dialog. Seems the software offers only the retagging but allows the suggested edit anyway.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I assume that's the case with all non-CW questions and answers? Then I'd recommend filing a bug report on [metase], unless there already is on on this topic.

Comment: Done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121895/168273