# Who plans to go to the TUG 2013 conference in Japan?

Tags: discussion, tug, conferences

[TUG 2013](http://tug.org/tug2013/), this years meeting of the [TeX Users Group](http://tug.org/) will be in Tokyo, Japan, from October 23 to October 26.

Who would like to go there? Does anybody plan to make a presentation?

> **Deadline** for presentaton proposals, bursary application and early registration discount is **July 15th**

Answer (score 26):

I posted this question because I consider to go there, and I'm interested if somebody else would like to attend too.

It's a long travel from Germany to Japan for me, so I think a good reason to attend would be making a presentation:

> Application of pgf/TikZ in Science and Technology

Since I'm maintaining [TeXample.net](http://texample.net/) with the [TikZ Example Gallery](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/), I had contact to many people who used TikZ in their works, mainly in natural sciences but also in electrical engineering and further areas. The presentation is intended to show TikZ' capabilities in this regard, and to talk about experiences with the application of TikZ.

Furthermore, TikZ is the most popular topic on TeX Stack Exchange, so I think it would be a great opportunity to represent our community at the conference in Japan.

My decision to go there may depend on the approval of our TeX.SE community members, if you would symbolically support it, if you like the trip plan and the presentation topic.

I made a similar trip in 2011, if you would like to read about it: [The TUG 2011 Experience](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/going-to-a-conference-the-tug-2011-experience).

Answer (score 22):

i've asked for time off to attend, and, barring disasters, hope to be there.

no decision yet on any presentation, but there are some possibly interesting topics that might be considered.

Comment: I'm planning to go (sadly the costs aren't inviting) and I really hope I can lure you to sign my TeXbook. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda -- well, i'm not the author, but i've been quoted there, and i'll be happy to sign that page.  (and to meet you -- tug meetings are really good for letting one associate faces with disembodied names.)

Comment: Considering faces, @Paulo 's one is all around the place :)

Comment: How many annual TUG conferences have you _not_ been to, Barbara? :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder -- two that i can think of offhand: the first one in india, and the one in china.  i do think, though, that nobody else has been to more, or maybe even as many.  (i know nelson beebe's record comes close.)

Answer (score 19):

I would love to go to TUG 2013 in Japan. I would have visited TUG 2012 but couldn't because of my PhD studies.

As a presentation topic I would like to talk about some parts I contributed to. I think either a talk about using stand-alone diagrams etc. in larger document, e.g. `standalone` with a comparision to the `externalise` TikZ library. An alternative would be the different possibilities of including and modify image and text content using `graphicx` and `adjustbox`.

Answer (score 16):

I will be there, of course ;-) If there are any questions concerning planning, travel etc, I will try my best to help

Answer (score 9):

I had really hoped to go but it's looking impossibly tight with my end-of-semester teaching.

I've enjoyed TUGs 2010 and 2012 and would highly recommend the trip!

Comment: Similar story here, except its the start of term for me.

Comment: i've enjoyed the tug conferences i've been to, but there is no way i could even imagine travelling to japan.  so i shan't be there.

Comment: @wasteofspace Only one thing for it: we'll have to volunteer to hold it in the UK in 2015!

Comment: @JosephWright: ooh I'd go to UK for that! `:)`

Comment: I also wish to attend TUG-2013. :) Attended TUG in 2002, 2004,2008 and 2011. It is really memorable experience. One should not miss it.

Answer (score 9):

My presentation's abstract is here: [TeX Live for Android: Development and usage](https://www.tug.org/tug2013/abstracts/ma.txt).

One of my friend, Jie Su, also provided a presentation: [A short history of TeX in China](https://www.tug.org/tug2013/abstracts/su.txt).

We will introducing PUTeX to the TeX world.

Comment: Typo: `\acor` → `\acro` in your abstract.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch The `\acro` macro is added by TUG13 committee. These two abstracts are modified by them, and the typo maybe comes from one of them.

Comment: BTW, don't forget to send me the data I asked you for!

Comment: @norbert I will ask Jie Su for his plan. We have not contacted with each other for several days.

Answer (score 7):

I'd really like to go. Not sure I can yet bit its on my wishlist

Answer (score 2):

I would like to make a presentation about programming video games in LaTeX using the build in functionality in PDF files that is supported by Adobe reader.