# Who plans to go to the TUG 2015 conference in Germany?

Tags: discussion, tug, conferences

[TUG 2015](http://tug.org/tug2015/), this years meeting of the [TeX Users Group](http://tug.org/) will be in Darmstadt, Germany, from July 20 to 22.

Who would like to go there? Does anybody plan to make a presentation?

> - April 10 - bursary application deadline.
> - May 1 - deadline for abstracts for presentation proposals.
> - May 15 - deadline for early bird registration discount.
> - June 1 - deadline for preprints to be in the printed program.

<sup>*(Thread plagiarized from the [last one by Stefan](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3336/who-plans-to-go-to-the-tug-2013-conference-in-japan).)*</sup>

**late edit:** 
The [program and participants list](http://tug.org/tug2015/program.html)
is posted on the TUG 2015 web site.

Comment: barring disasters, i shall be there, lurking as is my wont.

Comment: @yo' -- "lurking" just means, roughly, "hanging around without making much noise".

Comment: I'd love to attend, Darmstadt being only about four hours by train from Zurich (my current home base). Unfortunately [!], I'm going to be based in Singapore from mid-March and mid-August, and I can't think of a reason for my employer to send me to the Frankfurt area in July... :-(

Comment: I'd like to go since I'm going to stay in Poland from March 1st to end of August. Does anybody know the easiest way to go there from Bydgoszcz? Is there a direct flight?

Comment: @Sigur There are direct flights from all around Poland to Frankfurt, namely from: Warsaw, Krakow, Gdańsk, Katowice, Wrocław, Poznań, or from Berlin (may be the cheapest). Then there's a quick train from the airport to Darmstadt. Or, you can go by train with 2 changes in Berlin Ostbf and Frankfurt Hbf.

Comment: @yo', thanks. I am Googling to know where the city is. A flight from Bydgoszcz would be nice since I'm afraid to take a train to Poznań since I'm not able to follow one word in Polish. Imagine if the train change the platform... lol

Comment: @Sigur Then take a train to Berlin, you've got some chance of a foreign language in an intl train (anyways, peak in the chat, we may think something out. I live in the country just next door you know `:-)` )

Comment: @yo', thanks. I'll keep in mind. I'm going from Sao Paulo to Toruń next Sunday.

Comment: will there be recording of the talks/presentations made so others can watch them? I hope the talks can be made available on-line somewhere.

Comment: @Nasser It has been brought up to the right people and they shall keep you posted.

Comment: Two weeks before "my" baby is scheduled... and within school's summer vacation here (Berlin), so I think about joining, but there are obstacles.

Comment: Guys, don't forget to take lots of photos :-)

Answer (score 24):

I'm planning to go. And I'll probably submit a paper.

Not traveling by train, like Joseph, but by motorbike, of course. `;-)`

Comment: Drive safely, @egreg.

Comment: https://youtu.be/WBZXGxCXhFI

Answer (score 22):

I plan to attend, to put faces to names of many of the wonderful people here on this site (and elsewhere too), and also to learn about new, exciting developments in the world of TeX and Friends!

I submitted an abstract with the title:

> Pretty-printing Git commit history graphs with PGF/Ti*k*Z

**Update:** [My abstract](https://www.tug.org/tug2015/abstracts/gessler.txt) was accepted by the conference committee and is now listed on the [program page](https://www.tug.org/tug2015/program.html).

Comment: I can't attend TUG but I'll be interested in seeing your talk notes and ongoing development in this direction!

Answer (score 21):

I'll be going: my first TUG meeting :-) The plan is to talk about the recent work I've been doing on case changing and other things that need Unicode data, so something like

> Joseph's Adventures in Unicode-land

paired with one about the galley entitled

> Through the `\parshape`, and what Joseph found there

Comment: Good to know I'll meet you finally :-)

Comment: Or maybe Joseph's Multi-coded Coat?

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm hoping to come up with something better :-)

Comment: i'm really rather sorry that your original title wasn't accepted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Karl wanted something 'searchable': I plan to stick to the original at the event

Comment: I'm officially attending; just booked flights. Really looking forward to properly meeting :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Now I have two talks, so I am sticking to the fun title at least at the meeting

Answer (score 20):

Guess the answer in my case is going to be yes (might even cycle there) and yes (I plan to give a talk) -- see you there folks

Comment: From Mainz to Darmstadt, sounds like a cycling distance :-) Lucky you!

Comment: well it is (50km maybe) but not to go back and forth on a daily basis :-) ... let's see what the weather is going to be like and then I decide

Comment: 37 km centre-to-centre. And 3 times is not "a daily basis" ;)

Comment: what I meant is that I have no intention of cycling home in the evenings and back next morning (on a daily basis) but rather spend time with friends - and it is 42,5km according to Mr. Google

Answer (score 19):

I plan to be there and I plan to submit an abstract, too, with the preliminary title:

> Creating university journal and theses LaTeX classes/templates.

(As a note, it seems that I have currently one empty seat for anybody on the axis Prague--Nuremberg--Darmstadt, probably Sunday overnight in and Thursday morning out.)

Answer (score 17):

I need to get a move on to organise it, but I'd like to attend this year as well. Especially if Joseph will be there, since we've never met before! But I'll need to come up with something to talk about quick smart…

Comment: Promises, promises ... I still can’t see your name on http://tug.org/tug2015/program.html ;-)

Comment: Erg... you're right—I need to get my act together!

Comment: So you *are* still planning to go?  Great!

Comment: Just booked my flights… finally!

Comment: Fantastic :-)  Looking forward to finally meeting you.

Comment: Agreed! It has taken me quite some time. Might need to start practising my beer drinking? I'm a little rusty these days I hate to admit.

Answer (score 16):

Me too planning to come for TUG-15. :)

There is a  mailing list for TUG-15 possible attendees.
[TUG-15 mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tug2015-attendees)

It will be great to discuss travels plans  on mailing list. So that one can refer back to the information specially about travel plans etc. of others to join for travel.

Answer (score 15):

I will try to attend just for the lolz and of course a little bit of autobahn naughtiness...

I don't have any idea for an abstract yet and probably I won't anyways. So it depends on how much I can spare.

Answer (score 14):

I will attend TUG 2015. I submitted an [abstract](https://www.tug.org/tug2015/abstracts/cretel.txt) entitled

> Functional data structures in TeX

which was accepted.

Answer (score 13):

I'd like to go as well but am not sure if it fits my schedule.

Answer (score 13):

I'm planning to go. And I don't plan to submit a paper.

Answer (score 6):

I plan to arrive Sunday and to stay for the whole conference. Luckily my job projects will allow it, even better, I can do it as a business travel. At work people saw my TikZ generated network architecture drawings.

Comment: I think many people will be envious of being able to treat this as business!

Comment: That's because I could show my employer that TeX can improve our work-flow and the results both in design phase and in documentation of projects. I'll pay the price by actually introducing TeX as a work tool here.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Please consider writing up for all of us the lessons you learned as you have and continue to "introduce TeX as a work tool".

Answer (score 4):

I'll be there; arriving on Sunday and departing on Thursday. We should organize a TeX.SE [BoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birds_of_a_feather_%28computing%29) session.

Comment: What's a 'BOF session'?

Comment: @JosephWright: I've added a link. :-)

Answer (score 4):

me ................................................................